# Can outbreak chains loop?

Tags: pandemic

Is it possible for outbreak chains to loop - would it be possible for a city to experience an outbreak twice in the same round as a result of a chain?

Comment: If chains were possible, they would always be infinite, meaning they would instantly cause you to lose the game.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.  The [rules](http://www.zmangames.com/boardgames/files/pandemic/Pandemic_Rules.pdf) state "Note that each city may only outbreak once in each chain reaction."